# Copy array to dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, arrays, memory, pointers, dynamic

I got my code working, but i feel as if there is a faster way to do this especially in my function copy. here is my code. can this be any faster? this is in C btw. Also when i return cpy from the function does it delete the dynamic memory since its out of scope? I don't want to have memory leaks :P

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
double *copy(double a[], unsigned ele);
int main(){
    double arr[8], *ptr;
    unsigned i=0;
    for(;i<7;i++){
        scanf_s("%lf", &arr[i]);
    }
    ptr=copy(arr, 8);
    for(i=0;i<7; i++)
        printf("%f", ptr[i]);

}

double *copy(double a[], unsigned ele){
    double *cpy= malloc(sizeof(double)*ele);
    int i=0;
    for(;i<ele; i++)
        cpy[i]=a[i];
    return cpy;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace your `for` with a `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(cpy, a, ele * sizeof *cpy);
```

Other than that what you're doing it pretty okay: you're returning a pointer, thus the caller has a chance to `free` it.

Also I consider it good practice NOT to call `free` if you're going to exit - the OS will collect the memory anyway.

Comment: oh thats good to know thanks :). My professor however wants us to do it manually to see what's happening. Oh ok so i dont need to call free in this situation.

Comment: @NimaGanjehloo Well, the OS doesn't really care about `malloc`. It will take the memory back anyway.

Comment: Seems we posted the same solution. :-) I am very curious about why you say its a good practice to NOT call free before an exit though Cnicutar. While obviously it doesn't matter in trivial programs like this in my business a good cleanup routine is important. If you don't cleanup its much harder to track bugs down in Valgrind. What's your reasoning behind this best practice? Perhaps I should post a question on this...

Comment: @DavidMokonBond Some time ago I read a post from `R..` about this. The post detailed how the useless free can actually slow down things a lot. But yes, a "correct" malloc/free scenario is required for the sake of memory leak checkers. And it's not just trivial programs: if you're going to exit the `free` won't do anyone any good.

Comment: I consider good practice exactly the opposite: always call explicit free! (just wrote it, otherwise it wouldn't be worth mentioning it). It is a good "memory exercise", and you won't be accustomed to leave it "since the program is going to exit"... If it slows the exit, I wonder if there are optimizers who are able to remove free when they recognize the only flow/path the program can go from there is an exit... However, it is worth mentioning the fact that *not all OSs are able to free automatically the memory allocated by a program*!! So, after all, it's good practice always to free memory.

Comment: @cnicutar Ok. Also if you have any open handles that you don't close that could be a problem. If you find that link I'd be interested. I guess I just normally don't care if shutdown takes a little bit of time.

Answer (score 5):

Use Memcpy. It might be able to take advantage of your underlying hardware etc... No need to reinvent the wheel. :-)

```
void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );


double *copy(double a[], unsigned ele){
    size_t size = sizeof(double)*ele ;
    double *cpy= malloc(size);
    memcpy( cpy, a, size ) ;
    return cpy;
}
```

Comment: `int size = sizeof(double)*ele` You might want to change it to `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

> does it delete the dynamic memory since its out of scope

No, it doesn't: the only memory that goes out of scope is the one holding the pointer; you return the value of that pointer, and it's the only thing you need to access the memory you malloc-ed and which stays malloc-ed until you free it explicitly.

> I don't want to have memory leaks

Memory leaks happen when you get memory that you won't release. Indeed, your code have a memory leak: you do not `free` the memory the pointer is returned by copy: `free(ptr);` at the end of your code. In this case, it does not matter too much, but it's a good practice to avoid to forget it.

Note also that if the memory would be freed automatically when a pointer to it goes out of scope, it would be freed from inside the copy function itself and you would return an invalid pointer; and then there would be a lot of double free and alike, each time a pointer goes out of scope! Fortunately this does not happen since memory you got using malloc must be explicitly freed with free.