# How to copy from static array to dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, memcpy

Why does `b` not hold `1., 2.`?

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 2

void main() {
    double a[LEN] = {1, 2};
    double* b = malloc(LEN * sizeof(*b));

    memcpy(b, a, LEN);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2f ", b[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Instead, I get

```
> gcc code.c                                                                                                                                                         
> ./a.out                                                                                                                                                                                   
0.00 0.00
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy array to dynamically allocated memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577787/copy-array-to-dynamically-allocated-memory)

Comment: It does show that memcpy is the right tool, but here obviously getting the size right was the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `sizeof` in the `memcpy`

```
memcpy(b, a, LEN * sizeof *b);
```

As noted by @tstanisl in the comments, `LEN * sizeof *b` is the same as `sizeof a`, so you could make it:

```
double* b = malloc(sizeof a);
memcpy(b, a, sizeof a);
```

Also note that `void main()` isn't a valid signature for `main`. It should be `int main()`.

Comment: I JUST realized. Where is the automatic pair programmer tool that hints to these idiotic mistakes?

Comment: @fhchl LOL :-D Yeah, I've needed one of those myself.

Comment: it would be simpler and less error prone to use `memcpy(b, &a, sizeof a);`

Comment: @tstanisl `&a` makes a `double(*)[LEN]` instead of a `double*`. I find the latter clearer/simpler. I can agree to some extent about `sizeof a` but I went with `*b` for consistency with the `malloc`.

Comment: @fhchl `gcc -Wall -Werror` can help with some of those.

Comment: my variant will work with whatever `a` is going to be, not only `type[LEN]`

Comment: @tstanisl Yes, these `void*` functions are "forgiving" and don't care. I still like to match the types as best I can _as-if_ the function was actually `memcpy(double*, const double*, size_t);`

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m these flags don't seem to catch the above problem. Hints to that main should return `int` though...

Comment: They catch many other problems though. They [should be your default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).